# Is it necessary to pack firefox extension files into an xpi even on development?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am developing an extension for Mozilla Firefox. Is there any way in which I can develop without packing the files into an xpi for every change I make (like in Chrome)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. To do this, first close Firefox.

Then create a file in your profiles extensions directory that has the same ID as your extension.

In that file, you should place the fully qualified path to where you are developing your extension. In particular, to the same directory as the install.rdf.

When Firefox is restarted, it should ask you if you want to install the extension. Once you've done that, the extension will run from the local copy. After you make changes, you just need to close and restart the browser.

For more information, check this page out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Setting_up_extension_development_environment

I also recommend you install the Developer Assistant - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/extension-developer/ - which will set some prefs that make it easier to create Firefox extensions.